# NanoPi Neo Air microSD в качестве дополнительного хранилища памяти

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Есть NanoPi NEO Air, имеющая на борту 8гб eMMC. В ее внутреннюю память установлена ОС friendlyARM. Плата имеет также слот под microSD. Слот рабочий - с помощью microSD устанавливалась ОС, однако вставленную в этот слот карточку ОС не видит - карточка не отображается как диск в fdisk -l и не появляется в качестве устройства в /dev/.
В чем может быть причина? Как чинить?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему заменой ОС. Вместо nanopi-neo-air_friendlycore-xenial_4.14_armhf поставил nanopi-neo-air_friendlycore-xenial_3.4_armhf.

Comment: Позже перешел на focal debian от armbian, т.к. nanopi-neo-air_friendlycore-xenial_3.4_armhf не поддерживает g_mass_storage. В дистрибутиве от armbian работает все, что мне требуется - microSD, g_mass_storage, видео (проверял на motioneye). Возможно, кому-то пригодится